# HideSoftKeyboard not working in onClickListener

Tags: android

I want to hide the keyboard whenever an element from the dropdown of an autoCompleteteTextView is selected.
I've written this code and it's working without any error but what really happening is whenever I click the autoCompleteteTextView, keyboard comes and goes in an instant which I know because of the hideSofInputFromWindow in the onClick function. Here's the Java code:

```
package random.one.com.Perfecto;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

    public class Home extends AppCompatActivity   implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        private AutoCompleteTextView textView1;
        private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
        private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
        private AdView mAdView;
        private View view;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
            mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            final ImageView toolbar1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Toolbar1);
            final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
            toolbar1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

            }
            });
            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
            ViewPager vp_pages= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp_pages);
            PagerAdapter pagerAdapter=new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            vp_pages.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
            TabLayout tbl_pages= (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbl_pages);
            tbl_pages.setupWithViewPager(vp_pages);
            final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                    this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                    getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Loc_names));
            textView1 =(AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.acT1);
            textView1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            textView1.setThreshold(1);
            textView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View arg0) {

                    textView1.showDropDown();
                    hideKeyBoard(view);
                    String city = arrayAdapter.getItem(3);
                    TextView tv =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
                    tv.setText(city);
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
        public void hideKeyBoard(View view){
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),0);}
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                  return true;
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.nav_Home) {
                // Handle the camera action
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_Route) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_Map) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_Share) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_About) {

            }

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }
        class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
            public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }
            @Override
            public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        return new Metro();
                    case 1:
                        return new Bus();
                }
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 2;
            }
            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                    //
                    //Your tab titles
                    //
                    case 0:
                        return "Metro";
                    case 1:
                        return "Bus";

                    default:
                        return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So, Is there any way by which the keyboard hides only when a dropdown item is clicked.
Also How to get which item is clicked(position) through this method.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move below lines to code below, see comment:

```
hideKeyBoard(view);
```

-hide keyboard on dropdown selection:

```
 textView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
          hideKeyBoard(view);//move here
          String selection = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);//get item selected

    }
});
```

-You can get which item is clicked with the position from onItemClick above.

Comment: i think if condition is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to bother you guys.
here's the solution.
First Copy these lines as provided by ScottS (Thank you)

```
 textView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
          hideKeyBoard(view);//move here
          String selection = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);//get item selected

    }
});
```

Then copy these lines I used:

```
textView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View arg0) {

                    textView1.showDropDown();
                    hideKeyBoard(view);
                    String city = arrayAdapter.getItem(3);
                    TextView tv =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
                    tv.setText(city);
                }
            });
```

One thing to note is copying the above code below did nothing. Thank you all.